# Custom HorizontalSctollView with TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have some category like shown in fig-1.I have used `HorizontalScrollView`for category scrolling but when scroll scrolling progress display in the bottom of the textview(Give in picture).Actually don't want to show this and also want to put two button for left and right scroll(shown in fig-2).I have searched lot but haven't done this, if you have any idea please suggest me.**fig-1**
[image]

[image]

**fig-2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this property in HorizontalScrollView

```
android:scrollbars="none" in your xml file for disable scrollbar as picture 1.

<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:scrollbars="none" >
```

**Try Following xml for Solution of Picture 2.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>         

    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none" 
        android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp">
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check this [link](http://pavantilak.blogspot.in/2012/02/code-to-display-horizontal-scrollview.html) .

Comment: Thanks @Chirag for support its working,But tell me one thing for fig-2.We have to scroll text on clicking onleft left and right button.So how to do this..

Comment: My question is not hide arrow.I just have to scroll on clicking on array button.So if u have any idea please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

you can delete the scrollbar simply writting in the HorizontalScrollView definition:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this attribute `android:scrollbars="none"` to see if it works. =)